# PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Unresponsive on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have an few apps that are using the iOS barcode scanner plugin for PhoneGap. They have been working until about a two weeks ago, but they are not longer responsive after initializing. Has anybody else had this problem?

What is happening is that the scanner opens, but it will not read a QR or barcode. The view is unresponsive; you cannot cancel out of the view or have any way of getting back to the main application. The only way to exit the scanner is to hit the home button and manually kill the app.

I have built the apps with Xcode 6.2 and 6.3 and tested on iOS 8.2 and 8.3.

Is this a known issue? I cannot find any info.

Comment: Do other (empty?) phonegap projects work?

Comment: @Sirens Everything in my other apps that use the same framework (Sencha Touch :( ) works fine, and the rest of the application works fine. The plugin also works fine for Android. This is specifically an iOS issue which leads me to believe that this has to with some of the newer iOS updates. I hope that this thread can be useful to the rest of the community.

Comment: I don't know really. Can you file a bug report please?

Comment: @Sirens Absolutely I can do that to help. Where can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating the plugin. There where a couple of changes in the past month that I was unaware of. The update was found here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner